# Resilient Channel and Drywall Orientation

Tags: drywall, construction, drywall-anchor

I’ve got a 20’x12’ vaulted ceiling, 4/12 pitch that I want to install resilient channel on to reduce the risk of cracking; sound damping is not important. Trusses are just plain 2x6’s in the roof. Would I install the resilient channel perpendicular or parallel to the trusses, and subsequently what direction would I install my sheeting in relation to the RC?  I haven’t been able to find any good info online or in manufacturers install specs in relation to vaulted ceilings.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perpendicular.

I found this

"Resilient channel should be installed on Cathedral Ceilings (single or double angled ceiling) with the center of the face of the channel 6 inches from the top to permit a floating angle wallboard installation. Resilient channel must be installed with mounting flange down."

at the following website.

https://www.wconline.com/articles/89218-preventing-ceiling-cracking-with-resilient-channels

And of coarse much info is available on YouTube such as this [YouTube vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYyZ9zonfdg).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the boards are right angles to the channels too.